# Sudden change of Permissions

Tags: permissions, mount

I have a pc with Ryzen 7 2700X, Asus Prime B450M-A and 32 GB RAM. My main OS is ubuntu 18.04 in a SSD, a secondary boot with win 10 1903 in another SSD, a nvme Force MP510 240 GB for my VM's, and 2 HDD's for storage. Force MP510 and the 2 HDD's are set with manual mount options from Gnome Disks to mount automatically in /media. Up to yesterday Everything worked fine. Today suddenly when I try to create a file or a folder in one of those 3 disks (even when using sudo mkdir) I get error unable to create directory "A" : read-only file system. I tried sudo chmod a+rwx /path -R and it didn't work. I tried chown user:group /path didn't work either. Does anyone know how to make my disks available again without a format?

Comment: What is the format of the drives you are trying to mount in /media, eg are they all ext4?

Comment: sorry forgot to mention. All three are NTFS in order to be used by windows too

Comment: It might be a little more tricky but try this one first. Unmount any drive from /media so the folder is now empty. Then  change its ownership to your usename: `sudo chown username /media`. Then change permissions: `sudo chmod -R 750 /media` (or use 755 if you want  others to have access to folder and files). Then run `ls -l /media` to check permissions/ownership are correct. If so try mounting drives and check their permissions.

Comment: Windows NTFS does not support Linux type ownership & permissions. More likely that Windows fast start up is on. Even if you turned it off before Windows updates may turn it back on. http://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/ubuntu-16-showing-windows-10-partitions Are drives internal or external USB?

Comment: In this case we're talking about Linux supporting NTFS and using its own permission system, irrespective of Windows permissions. Seems to work fine for me. Of course if there's Windows encryption involved then that would cause a problem.

Comment: Paul Benson I tried to change ownership in /media but it remains to root. It doesn't change ownership. As root it has permission for everything. as for the latest comment. Yesterday I could write a file, create a folder to all of these disks.

Comment: Oldfred up to yesterday I didn't have a problem with permissions and ownership and I was working fine with both windows and ubuntu. The drives are all internal and were mounting normally. I could open them normally with nemo but could not copy a file in, write a file or create afolder

Comment: @Kostas. Did you do as I suggested and unmount any drive in there first? Can you post output of `sudo ls -lR /media` in your question? You're now saying the drives are internal? So they boot from fstab?

Comment: oldfred you were right. It was fastboot after all. Thank you very much

Comment: Yeah I had them all unmounted and and the drive directories deleted. The answer was oldfred. Once I had fastboot unchecked and hybernation off I booted in ubuntu, mounted them and they worked fine. Anyway thank you for your interest and help